# How do I display all of one value from a nested list?

Tags: python

If I have a nested list like this (the actual data will be a random length):

```
data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['1', '2'],['3','4']]
```

How would I display only the first item in each list (a, 1, 3) using a loop.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    print() #what goes here?
```

Comment: Try: `[x[0] for x in data]`

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh, it fails when a list is empty (which can be possible as the question says the length is random)

Comment: `[x[0] for x in data if x]` is probably better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways.

To continue using an index like you currently are:

```py
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data[i][0])
```

In this method we get each nested array by accessing `data[i]` then access the first element of the nested array by accessing `data[i][0]`.

However using an index to iterate through a list is not considered very pythonic; a more common way would be as follows:

```py
for nestedArr in data:
    print(nestedArr[0])
```

By using `in` in this way each nested array is assigned to `nestedArr`, then we can access the first element of that nested array the same way as above.

Note:
Be careful to make sure that each element in `data` is actually a list and that each nested list has at least 1 element. You may wish to use an if statement and the `len` function to verify this before attempting to print the first element.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data[i][0])
```

or

```
for i in data:
    print(i[0])
```

This code will display the first value of nested list at index i. But I'm confused if those data will be stored in another list or tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest method is list comprehension:

```
print([e[0] for e in data])
```